# Unique naming/labeling of $40$-node strongly regular graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, strongly-regular-graph

[Brendan McKay's webpage](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/data/graphs.html) lists all possible $40$-node strongly regular graphs. Is there a standard  way to name them uniquely?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly what you had in mind, but in the context of displaying information on web pages, there is a need for a canonical labelling of graph isomorphism classes.

The [proposed web standard is here](http://json-ld.github.io/normalization/spec/).  As is typical with these things, the standards are debated for some years before they may be accepted, but this one seems relatively stable.  Code for evaluating it (which also allows you to examine the implementation of the algorithm) [is here](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/pyld).  In terms of a "standard way" of naming these things, this is about as standard as you can get.

The graph isomorphism portion of the RDF specification is an attempt to answer your question (for any graph).  Since we're considering 40-node strongly regular graphs and there's only 28 of them, you could also encode them in some fashion and sort lexicographically.  But both these approaches may fail on aesthetic grounds-- maybe we'd really like to describe some relationship between the isomorphism classes that characterizes them in a mathematically meaningful way.  Perhaps that's the real question?

Comment: I tried to read those documents, but I literally cannot find an actual graph isomorphism / canonicalisation procedure in there. It talks about issuers, and quads, and blank nodes and Hash N-degree quads, and lots of acronyms that lead to other things I don't understand. But I couldn't see anything that I could recognise as graph isomorphism?

Comment: @GordonRoyle , I am extremely sympathetic to your reaction to the teeth-gritting opacity of the language.  As for the GI connection, just search for the phrase "graph isomorphism problem".  For a possibly clearer explanation, check out Section 1.2.1 here: https://w3c.github.io/lds-wg-charter/explainer.html#generalProblem  , especially the Arnold/Longley paper.  (Full disclosure: I'm part of the "Mirabolic Consulting" that gets mentioned in passing.)